# unable to find git in your path when i try running dart, flutterfire commands

Tags: visual-studio-code

[so i've been having this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJj78.png)

i can run git and flutter command in vscode but somehow the others i couldn't i'm pretty sure i installed git correctly and added the correct path to it

[here's my env path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWR76.png)

i've already tried adding path manually on settings.json in vscode but couldn't work i've tried reinstalled git too but the problems still there

Comment: Please embed your screenshot in the question.